# What is a u-coordinate within Elliptic Curve Diffie-Hellman using the Montgomery ladder

Tags: elliptic-curves, diffie-hellman, montgomery-ladder

I am trying to understand the below paragraph.

> Elliptic curve Diffie-Hellman is often calculated using the Montgomery
>   ladder. This gives a simple and efficient calculation that is
>   naturally resistant to timing side channels. The Montgomery ladder
>   also allows each party's public key to be a Montgomery u-coordinate.
>   Using a single coordinate instead of the whole point makes public keys
>   smaller without the expense of point decompression.

I read about Elliptic curves and Montgomery ladder at Wikipedia. Can someone please explain this paragraph in naive language.Also please answer below questions.

1. What is Montgomery u-coordinate.
2. A brief explanation of requirement of point decompression.

Comment: Welcome to crypto, interesting first question! Note that I made your title somewhat more specific and changed the way that the list is generated, you can take a look at the edit to see how.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Montgomery form and ladder

People are typically introduced to elliptic curves in Weierstrass form, namely the points $(x,y)$ that satisfy $y^2 = x^3 + ax + b$. Specifying $a$ and $b$ pick out a particular curve.

There is an alternative representation of elliptic curves, called the [Montgomery form:](https://www.hyperelliptic.org/EFD/g1p/auto-montgom.html)

$Bv^2 = u^3 + Au^2 + u$

[Peter Montgomery introduced this form in his 1987 paper.](https://cr.yp.to/bib/1987/montgomery.pdf) Here, the points are $(u,v)$ pairs and specifying $A$ and $B$ pick out a curve. You can [convert from one form to the other.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Montgomery_curve) The $u$ here is the u-coordinate you referred to.

### Why is this useful?

When doing scalar multiplication on elliptic curves over a field $\mathbb{F}_p$, you have to do a lot of modular divisons / inverses. However, in Montgomery form, $u$ and $v$ are [projective coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_space). What this gets you is letting you postpone expensive division operations for as long as possible, giving nice speedups. So think of $u$ as a ratio of two coordinates, similar to (*not* equal to!) $x/y$.

Very roughly, the Montgomery ladder is doing a "double-and-add" operation on a point in projective space. The input to the ladder is a scale factor $k$ and the u-coordinate, and the output is *only* the u-coordinate of the scaled point. That's why the Montgomery ladder is called a *single-coordinate ladder.* If necessary and if you have both $u$ and $v$, [you can compute both coordinates of the scaled point](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1703.01863.pdf), but if you only need the scaled $u$, you get this quickly without having to spend time computing the "baggage" of the other coordinate, like with point compression and decompression.

### Point Compression and Decompression

See [Section 2.3 for a description of the calculation to do point compression and decompression](https://eprint.iacr.org/2012/309.pdf). The basic idea is it's better to carry one number around than two if you can, so take $(u,v)$ in projective space and combine the two coordinates into a "compressed" value $\tau$ which can later be "decompressed" into $(u,v)$ or $(x,y)$ form. These compression and decompression operations involve taking [modular square roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tonelli%E2%80%93Shanks_algorithm) and modular inversion which are expensive. The Montgomery ladder lets you avoid this computation.

Comment: I'm slightly confused by your second part. The Montgomery ladder doesn't need $v$ as input. But assuming that you do have it, you can recover the full point at the end. Otherwise you can't.

Comment: You are correct; I was inaccurate about the inputs to the ladder (in my implementations, I just threw $v$ away). I made some edits to that section; thank you!